# Android: Moving multiple objects

Tags: android

I was wondering- how can I move multiple objects (imageviews) in a view (any view) in Android? I just want a simple, general approach.

I have successfully implemented a surfaceview with multiple moving objects but each time an object moves, the whole canvas has to be updated even for the non moving objects, which is slowing the ui. I have tried fixing this for days, but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer:
http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/

Comment: no probs. the example is fantastic and can be extended and modified easily too. remember to change your layout to framelayout instead of absolute layout (which the author used) cos that is deprecated.